# Select on a HTML page the contains of two tags

Tags: html, parsing, c#-4.0, tags

This is my need. 
I have an html code like this :

```
<html>
<tag1>Title1</tag1>
<tag2>Value</tag2>
<tag3>Dont care</tag3>
<tag1>Title2</tag1>
<tag2>Value2</tag2>
<tag3>Dont care</tag3>
</html>
```

I would like to be able to have in a result a list of string or something looking like this in a result :

line1 : Title1, Value1
line2 : Title2, Value2 
etc, 
after having set the filter tag (in this case, tag1 and tag2).

Any ideas ? 
(in .NET 4.0 C#)

Comment: Presumably JavaScript? Plus, what have you tried/looked into?

Comment: No, it is not javascript. It is in order to have a document before publication on Internet, of each tags selected.

Comment: I mentionned html, in order to says it is not xml :)

Comment: Yes but you're describing a programatic process - HTML cannot do this alone. So what language do you want to use to do the actual matching and string generation, if not JS?

Comment: I mentionned it at the end of the code, C# 4.0

Comment: Your actual question doesn't make much sense, so please clarify a few things: Where are you getting the `<html>...</html>` string; is it held in a variable within a `C#` method? Probably obtained out of a database, or by parsing/scraping a web page. So once you get this `<html>...</html>` string, you wish to extract text out of it in a `key:value` pair way such that, `<tag1 />` (for instance) will be the `Key` and `<tag2 />` the `value`? So what happens to `<tag3 />`?

Comment: "- Where are you getting the <html>...</html> string;" : from a cell coming from a result from a database. "-  is it held in a variable within a C# method?" see my first answer. "So once you get this <html>...</html> string, you wish to extract text out of it in a key:value pair way such that, <tag1 /> (for instance) will be the Key and <tag2 /> the value? :" Yes that's it.  "So what happens to <tag3 />?" I dont need it on my result. . I'm currently watching if htmlAgilityPack is not the best solution to my problem, but I thougtht I would find a easier solution...

Comment: Easier or not is quite subjective. The `htmlAgilityPack` that you are using is known to be a very good fit for your use case. Are you having an issue using it?

Comment: Ok I found the solution thru the html AgilityPack. Thanks.